# Why randseed (randomize) is not initialized by default?

Tags: delphi

Why `randseed`,  the variable used to random number that we must initialize ourself by calling `randomize` is not **at least** initialized by default by delphi when the program start ? Without this vital initialization (Ex user forget to call randomize), random output are totally predictable. I m just curious if their is any reason for such behavior ...

Comment: It's quite useful for random output to be repeatable. For testing and development. And why should everybody pay the cost of initialising it if it isn't used. Many programs don't rely in Random.

Comment: is their really a cost to call GetTickCount at the start of the program (what randomize do) ? also if someone need the output to be repeatable (I guess 1 dev for 1000 need this) then he can do randseed := 0

Comment: And you are finding it hard to seed the rng? Anyway, I doubt anybody here will have knowledge of why it is this way.

Answer (score 4):

Your point makes sense. However, a similar argument can be made for a hundred other initializations that could conveniently be done for you at the start if program execution.

Since Delphi is a general purpose language, it must not make any assumptions about what you want your code to do. Seeding the randomizer takes a few computing cycles, as would all other initializations, however desirable and sensible  they may appear for your use case.

As for this particular case: there are scenarios imaginable where one does want the randomizer seeded from, say, system time, in order to have a repeatable set if numbers for tests. Of course, convenience makes sense for 99 out of a hundred cases, but not all of them.